Realistic outcome of probate if a will leaves nothing to surviving spouse?
From basic googling I did, sounds like (at least in New Jersey), if a spouse dies, the surviving spouse is likely to be able to challenge any will to get at least 1/3 of the assets, even if the will leaves them nothing.
However, what I was not able to figure out is, does this apply to common assets, or only assets solely belonging to deceased spouse, or both?
In other words, let's say the spouses have $1M in common assets, and the diseased spouse has $300K in pre-marital solely owned assets.
What exactly can the surviving spouse realistically get? (and vice versa, how much can a deceased  spouse ensure to keep away from surviving spouse even if the survivor successfully challenges the will?)
Intuitively I'm guessing surviving spouse would get all 100% of $1M common assets AND also $100K (33%) of solely-held assets even if the will said everything goes to charity. Is that correct?

The probate estate is made up of everything that does not pass by beneficiary designation or a joint tenancy with right of survivorship at death. The 1/3rd share is of the decedent's probate estate.
The probate estate is made up of assets owned only in the name of the deceased spouse or the spouse's share of an assets co-owned with someone (not necessarily a spouse) as a tenant-in-common (i.e. co-ownership without a right of survivorship), less any debts outstanding owed by the deceased spouse at the death of the deceased spouse.

Am I correct in interpreting this asnwer as validating the guess in the question? ($1M common assets are "joint tenancy" so basically pass to the surviving spouse 100% without probate, and $300K (obviously less debt) owned by dead spouse ends up in probate and presumably gets 33% assigned to surviving spouse regardless of the will?

@user3885 "common assets" is a highly ambiguous term. I don't know what that means.

I meant assets that would legally be considered "both" spouses' assets in case of divorce. For simplicity, let's state an example of $500K house in both spouses' names and $500K bank account in both spouses names, no other assets or liabilities.

@user3885 "I meant assets that would legally be considered "both" spouses' assets in case of divorce." This is irrelevant in the estate administration/probate context. Spousal rights at death and spousal rights in divorce in non-community property states use completely different conceptual frameworks to evaluate the issue. Likewise a house in both spouse's name could be joint tenancy with right of survivorship v. tenancy in common v. tenancy by entireties. A joint bank account normally has an implied right of survivorship and is a non-probate assets, but not 100% of the time.

What would make a normal typical savings account with both spouses name on them probateable? And "not 100%" - is that 99% or 1%? I am happy with an answer that covers 80% of cases, obviously with law there's always some weird rare exception, like with other areas of specialty, but 80/20 rule is good enough

@user3885 It isn't uncommon, for example, for someone to be a signer on an account without being an owner, especially for an older couple or in a second marriage.

Let's take the simplest, most un-weird, situation. Both spouses opened a new account after marriage, both owners, 100% money deposited after marriage, community property state. House owned by both spouses, both as far as finances and title. Is there any reasonable way this could be considered part of probate? On what grounds? There are no other assets (aside from 300K account dead spouse had from before marriage that never changed and WILL presumably be part of probate); no other liabilities, no other legit candidates for inheritance.

I am told that money paid into my private pension is currently mine, but if I die then according to my contract with the pension provider it is my wife’s money. She doesn’t inherit it, it’s just hers. And my wife knows a lady who married a divorced man who couldn’t be bothered changing the beneficiary of his pension, and the pension money was his ex wife's when  he died; his wife of 15 years got nothing of it.
